# Getting current location from google map in corona platform for iOS with java script

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-api-3, coronasdk

I am very stuck to getting current location from google map in corona sdk, i have already tried with google geo location ,
I tried following solution but in corona its not showing current location of the user
[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) and 
[this](http://toddmotto.com/using-html5-geolocation-to-show-current-location-with-google-maps-api/)
 also

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
          },
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        myOptions);

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                         position.coords.longitude);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
        });

        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
    }

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
      var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
      var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
      content: content
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using this in a native.newWebView?

Comment: no I'm using Corona mapview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corona native maps, using native.newMapView() are not "Google Maps" as in something that runs in the web browser or using the device's app directly.  On Apple, we use their built in Map SDK which happens to use the engine that drives Apple's Map app.  On Android, we use Google's Map SDK.

The main point is you can't use JavaScript like this in a Corona app that's using native.newMapView().  You might get it to work if you're using a webView since you can run JavaScript and your webView could embed a Google web page map.  That's why I had to ask the question.  Now that we know....

Corona SDK has several API calls that work with a native.newMapView that let you get address and location information.  Please see:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Map/index.html